# What version of PHP do current docs refer to?

Tags: php

Does anyone know what version of PHP https://secure.php.net/docs.php refers to?  I cannot find a reference to the version number anywhere.

Comment: It refers to all versions: you will see versions on each page command. I.e. [sqlite](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-open.php) (PHP 5 < 5.4.0); [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.importing.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: Good answer!  This should be an answer, not a comment.

Nevertheless, version numbers do not appear on every manual page.  For example, the page https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php has no mention of any version number.  For consistency, I would expect to see something like (PHP4, PHP5, PHP5) if the material on this page is valid for all supported versions.

Answer (score -1):

Each command reference page states the specific versions of PHP that the command applies to at the top of the page under the command name.

### Examples

- [`odbc_execute`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php)

  > (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
- [`PDO::exec`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

  > (PHP 5 >= 5.1.0, PHP 7, PECL pdo >= 0.1.0)
- [`array_column`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

  > (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)